# Scala: who can explain this?

Tags: scala, generics

Consider the following Scala code:

```
case class Data[T](value: Option[T]) {
  def get: T = try {
    doGet
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }

  def doGet: T = value match {
    case Some(v) => v
    case None => ().asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

Data[Unit](None).get
Data[Integer](None).get // which exception is thrown here?
```

[spoiler] It is a `ClassCastException`; who can explain why it is not caught and replaced by an `IllegalArgumentException`?

PS: To preempt any questions on why I would want to do this: this is a simplified version of some code that uses json4s to parse some string into an `Option[T]`; if the parsing fails `None` is returned, which is OK if `T` was `Unit` and not OK if `T` is some other type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Explanation

Exception isn't thrown here:

```
().asInstanceOf[T]
```

because this is an unchecked cast - JVM cannot verify if it is possible to cast `()` into `T`, because it has no information about `T` due to type erasure.

Instead, exception is thrown here

```
Data[Integer](None).get
```

because the result of `get` is cast into an `Integer` and that is something that JVM can verify. So, `ClassCastException` is actually thrown outside of `get`.

BTW, `javac` always warns about unchecked casts, I don't know why `scalac` doesn't.

### Workaround

To some extent, it is possible to work around type erasure here using `ClassTag` and reflection-based casting:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

case class Data[T: ClassTag](value: Option[T]) {
  def get: T = try {
    doGet
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }

  def doGet: T = value match {
    case Some(v) => v
    case None => classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]].cast(())
  }
}
```

### Hackaround

For this use case, you can inspect the `ClassTag` directly:

```
scala> case class Data[T](value: Option[T])(implicit t: ClassTag[T]) {
     | def get: T = value getOrElse (t match {
     |   case ClassTag.Unit => ().asInstanceOf[T]
     |   case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
     | })
     | }
defined class Data

scala> Data[Unit](None)
res6: Data[Unit] = Data(None)

scala> .get

scala> Data[Int](None).get
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Comment: Aha! Erasure! That's the key.

Comment: Can the code be modified to make the `get` throw the exception?

Comment: Note that your `ClassTag` workaround would not work if you try this reflection-based casting to cast, e.g., a `List[Int]` to a `List[String]`. It will silently work and then fail later, throwing again a `ClassCastException`. There's a reason why `runtimeClass` doesn't return `Class[T]`.

Comment: The `ClassTag` hackaround works well in this case, since only the `Unit` type needs special treatment and all other types (including parameterized ones) should cause the `IllegalArgumentException`. It is also possible to move the `implicit ClassTag` to the `get` definition.