# Scala: I managed to wrap a String into an Option[Double]... is that a bug?

Tags: scala, classcastexception

I just couldn't believe to my eyes when I saw the result... Just give a look to this code

```
object ScalaBug  {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // This goes OK
    val aa: Option[Double] = first[Double]("A string in a Double!!") 
    println(aa)
    println(aa.getClass())
    aa match {
       // ...but this raises an error
       case Some(v) => println(v.getClass())
       case None => None
    }

    // The call to the other methods fails...
    val bb: Double = second[Double]("Yet another string in a Double!!") 
    println(bb)
    val cc: Option[Double] = third[Double]("One more string in a Double!!") 
    println(cc)

  }

  def first[T](x: String): Option[T] = Some(x.asInstanceOf[T])

  def second[T](x: String): T = x.asInstanceOf[T]

  def third[T](x: String): Option[T] = { val d = x.asInstanceOf[T] ; Some(d)}
}
```

It seems that the bug is in the call to the constructor method of Some(): no casting happens here...

In fact the *third* method does the same of the *first* method but in two different steps and I got an error as expected.

I think this should be considered a bug. But I'd like to share my point of view with you experts.

Just for sake of clarity, I'm on scala 2.10.2 but I got it also with scala 2.10.4-RC1

Comment: This is not a bug. Using `asInstanceOf` like that is pretty much blackmailing the compiler into believing things that are not true. This plus type erasure = total mess.

Comment: So I guess that using .asInstanceOf method should be avoided... What is the better approach to casting types, then?

Comment: Like @ghik said, you can do all sorts of stupid things if you explicitly lie to the compiler. You should be able to do write pretty much identical code in Java using an explicit cast `(T)x`, and you could even use the new `Optional` type in Java 8 in place of Scala's `Option`.

Comment: @ghik: I'm curious—what does type erasure have to do with casting like this?

Comment: @Max the safe way to cast types is to use pattern matching.

Comment: @TravisBrown: without type erasure we should be able to use `classOf[T]` and every `a.asInstanceOf[T]` could be replaced with `classOf[T].cast(a)`. Actually in `C#` you'll get an exception on `(T)x`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Like @senia said, type erasure makes things worse, because casts like `asInstanceOf[T]` will not be checked even in runtime and this will result in super confusing situations like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773122/scala-who-can-explain-this

Comment: I guess I don't see that as type erasure making the mess worse so much as removing some possible motivations to muck around in the mess.

Comment: This question reads like those internet ads that must be irresistible because they keep showing up: Shocker! Sunnyvale housewife's secret to whiter teeth that Obama doesn't want you to know about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asInstanceOf` in generic code simply promises the compiler that you know that one thing is actually something else.  Whenever you get out of generic code and rely upon this behavior, false promises will blow up in your face.

This is how the JVM works: you need a specific class to test `instanceof`.